# Angular material version 5 - <mat-footer-row> not supported?

Tags: angular, angular-material, footer, mat-table

I am going to show the **total row** at the end of a **mat-table** and keep it **not sorted** and stay at the bottom.

I tried in the stackbiltz and it works pretty fine.

[mat-table sort and footer example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psfedx?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts)

Btw, this is built on angular **material v7.3.7** and my app is **v5.25**, and my app shows an error.

[image]

I checked the node-module and it seems to be that angular v5 doesn't support **mat-footer-row.**

Am I missing something?

Or **mat-footer-row** is supported in higher versions only?

If so, how can I add a total row which isn't sorted along with the other rows and kept at the bottom?

Can anyone help me with this, please?
Thanks in advance!!